# $(x,yz,t) = (x,y,t)z + (x,z,t)y$ holds in every Jordan algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, nonassociative-algebras, jordan-algebras

The identity

$$(x,yz,t) = (x,y,t)z + (x,z,t)y$$

holds in every Jordan algebra. Remember that a Jordan algebra satisfies $xy=yx$ and $(x^2,y,x) = 0$ for all $x,y$. Here $(a,b,c) = (ab)c - a(bc)$ is the associator.

**Comments:** For one hand
$$(x,yz,t) = (x(yz))t - x((yz)t)$$
and on the other hand
$$(x,y,t)z + (x,z,t)y = ((xy)t)z - (x(yt))z + ((xz)t)y - (x(zt))y.$$

I can't see why these expressions are the same using only the two identities above.

Comment: Where have you seen this identity? I have seen a similar relation but with $(yz, t, x)$ instead $(x, yz, t)$ and both are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the equality holds if $char(K)=2$.

However if $char(K)\neq2$, Shirshov proved (for example, see [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764388577)) that any Jordan Algebra satisfies the identity $((bc)a)d+((db)a)c+((cd)a)b-((ac)b)d-((da)b)c-((cd)b)a=0$

Making the changes $a\rightarrow t,b\rightarrow x,c\rightarrow y,d\rightarrow z$

You will have $\color{blue}{((xy)t)z}+\color{green}{((zx)t)y}+((yz)t)x\color{blue}{-((ty)x)z}-\color{green}{((zt)x)y}-((yz)x)t=0$

Or simply $\color{blue}{((xy)t)z-((ty)x)z}+\color{green}{((zx)t)y-((zt)x)y}=((yz)x)t-((yz)t)x$

Using the commutativity you get the desired result $\color{blue}{(x,y,t)z}+\color{green}{(x,z,t)y}=(x,yz,t)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.